# Does anyone know how to deploy a Django project which has Postgres Database on minikube locally. any refrences i try all of them which i found in

Tags: django, postgresql, kubernetes, minikube

here is My Deployment files

```
------
#Depployment Django
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: django1
  labels:
    app: django1
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: django-container
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: django-container
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: todo
          image: jayantkeer/image-of-kubernets
          command: ["python manage.py makemigrations", "python manage.py migrate","python manage.py"] # runs migrations and starts the server
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8000
          env:
            - name: POSTGRES_USER
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: postgres-credentials
                  key: user

            - name: POSTGRES_PASSWORD
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: postgres-credentials
                  key: password

            - name: POSTGRES_HOST
              value: postgres-service
```

And postgres service file

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: todo
  labels:
    app: todo
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app:  django-container
  ports:
    - port: 8000
      targetPort: 8000
-------
and postgres deployment
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: postgres-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: postgres-container
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: postgres-container
        tier: backend
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: postgres-container
          image: postgres:9.6.6
          env:
            - name: DATABASE_USER
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: postgres-credentials
                  key: user

            - name: DATABASE_PASS
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: postgres-credentials
                  key: password

            - name: POSTGRES_DB
              value: kubernetes_django

          ports:
            - containerPort: 5432
          volumeMounts:
            - name: postgres-volume-mount
              mountPath: /var/lib/postgresql/data

      volumes:
        - name: postgres-volume-mount
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: postgres-pvc
```

Comment: I don't see any question here. What happens when you deploy these manifests? Do they work? If not, what is the observed behavior -- are you seeing an error? Something else?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.